# Why don't background colors work in inline-grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I created two divs; one with a `display:inline-grid` property and another with `display:grid` property. I want to apply a background color to the child elements of both divs but the div with the `display:inline-grid` property is not coloring its elements.

**HTML and CSS code**

```css
#inline {
  display: inline-grid;
}

#block {
  display: grid;
}

div div {
  height: 50px;
}

div div:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: green;
}

div div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div div:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="inline">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="block">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The output is:
[image]

How can I color the divs inside the inline-grid div?

Comment: Your output image isn't actually displaying, might want to take a look at that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `display: inline-grid;` is a **[`inline`](https://codeburst.io/block-level-and-inline-elements-the-difference-between-div-and-span-2f8502c1f95b)** elements

> Basically, an inline element does not cause a line break (start on a
>   new line) and does not take up the full width of a page, only the
>   space bounded by its opening and closing tag. It is usually used
>   within other HTML elements.

if you want you can colour it by using some additional styles for sample `width:100%;` in your case:

```css
#inline {
  display: inline-grid;
  width:100%;
}
#block {
  display: grid;
}

div div {
  height: 50px;
}

div div:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: green;
}

div div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div div:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="inline">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="block">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

Being an inline element, it's width is defined by its content. But there is no content here.

Just add width:

```css
#inline {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 150px;
}

#block {
  display: grid;
}

div div {
  height: 50px;
}

div div:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: green;
}

div div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div div:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="inline">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="block">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "width" attribute to your division:

```
#inline {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just added width property to the #inline css and this is now working.

```
#inline {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You must know why you should use any display type and when to use it, this is the best way to have the result you need

**CSS Grid Layout Module**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" style="grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';">
  <div class="grid-item" style="grid-area: header">
    <h3>Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="grid-area: menu">
    <h3>Menu</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="grid-area: main">
    <h3>Main</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="grid-area: right">
    <h3>Right</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="grid-area: footer">
    <h3>Footer</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Grid Layout**

> The CSS Grid Layout Module offers a grid-based layout system, with
>   rows and columns, making it easier to design web pages without having
>   to use floats and positioning.

[More info ->](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)